# Angular 15 Universal (SSR) slow before load website

Tags: optimization, server-side-rendering, universal, angular15

I have a very slow problem during the initial loading of the website with Angular 15 Universal(SSR), of course, I'm sure there is no problem with CSR loading website.

This problem occurs when the NodeJS server loads the website for the first time.

When append `inlineCriticalCss = false` in `server.ts`, it loads much faster, but this has the work of messing website during first loading means that it loads with a delay CSS, and I also used optimization changes in `angular.json` file

```
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
    "minify": true,
    "inlineCritical": false
  },
  "fonts": true
},
```

in `angular.json`, But unfortunately, my problem was still not solved

I have searched a lot, there are links that raise this problem, but none of them solve my problem.